# Postgres: delete unreferenced entries in a giant table in chunks

Tags: postgresql

I've got a fairly large table, about 30 million rows. Many of the items are no longer referenced due to a previous bug where deletes weren't appropriately cascading.

Trying to do a simple DELETE WHERE ID_DOES_NOT_EXIST_IN_OTHER_TABLE is taking forever, ran all weekend and didn't finish and I had to eventually kill it. However, there's no urgency here, so I'd like to find a way to do this in increments. Postgres DELETE doesn't seem to allow the use of limit though.

What's a way to delete 100000 (to pick an arbitrary number) rows at a time so I can slowly work my way through the table and clean it up?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have good indexes, and hopefully this will help. Try using a CTE to mark a subset of ID's for deletion:

```
      WITH marked_ids as (
    SELECT my_table.id
      FROM other_table
     RIGHT
     OUTER
      JOIN my_table
    ON other_table.id = my_table.fk_id
     WHERE other_table.id IS NULL
     LIMIT 1000
)
DELETE 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM marked_ids);
```